# Data for sunburst charts with d3.hierarchy using D3js v4

Tags: arrays, json, d3.js, charts, sunburst-diagram

I am trying to get a sunburst chart using d3.hierarchy with d3js v4 . I did the same as an [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4348373)  here. But since the data I was getting as an array of objects and not the same as used in the example I did add a small function so that the data would be the same as from the example. Below is the function

```
const arrayToObject = (array) =>
    array.reduce((obj, item) => {
        obj[item.name] = item
        return obj
}, {})
```

Here is the link for the fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/snt1/mbszu1u5/8/

Thank You.

Comment: What's your question or problem?

Comment: @TomShanley  I get an error "Cannot read property 'data' of null" and get a black circle instead.

Comment: The docs show that the expected data format is an object with a property of `children` which is an array https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is an answer (I think it is) or I should post this as a comment **BUT** here's the thing with your code:

`d3.hierarchy()` looks for an object with "name" and "children" and manipulates the data which is then used by `partition(root)`.

If you debug the code at https://bl.ocks.org/maybelinot/5552606564ef37b5de7e47ed2b7dc099, you'll see that `d3.hierarchy()` receives an object as `{name: "flare", children: Array[15]}`

In your code, if I just wrap the `data` array in an object, say:
`{name: "test", children: data}`, it creates a sunburst with colors and appropriate titles.

Here's a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2104/q70yeqhe/1/) with the changes. (btw I've commented `arrayToObject`)

Hope this helps. :)